# matplotlib/geopands suddenly crippingly slow - same code fast just hours ago

Tags: python, matplotlib, maps, geospatial, geopandas

I experience something weird with plotting a simple map using geopands and matplotlib on jupyterlab. Although I have unchanged the code it suddenly runs crippingly slow (both on remote server and local machine; CPU load etc are in range and not the issue). We are now talking 50 Minutes rather than 50 seconds.

- Matplotlib Version 3.5.1
- Geopandas Version 0.12.0
- Pandas 1.4.2.
- Python 3.9.12

I am used to run cell by cell in jupyter; it occured first time after I hit restart kernel and run all cells at once.

It slows at this stage of the code: creating a simple plot (a map shapefile with coloured areas by variable):

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7.5,7.5), dpi = 100)

shape.plot(ax=ax, facecolor='Grey', color= 'white')
shape.plot(ax=ax, column='datacol', cmap='Blues');

ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_facecolor('xkcd:white')

fig.savefig(path, facecolor='white', dpi = fig.dpi)
```

Comment: what's length of `shape` has it changed?

Comment: 25121 rows; but as said unchanged.